# Python - matrix multiplication with sparse result

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

Suppose I have two dense matrices U (10000x50) and V(50x10000), and one sparse matrix A(10000x10000). Each element in A is either 1 or 0. I hope to find A*(UV), noting that '*' is element-wise multiplication. To solve the problem, Scipy/numpy will calculate a dense matrix UV first. But UV is dense and large (10000x10000) so it's very slow.

Because I only need a few elements of UV indicated by A, it should save a lot of time if only necessary elements are calculated instead of calculating all elements then filtering using A. Is there a way to instruct scipy to do this?

BTW, I used Matlab to solve this problem and Matlab is smart enough to find what I'm trying to do and works efficiently.

Update:
I found Matlab calculated UV fully as scipy does. My scipy installation is simply too slow...

Comment: Just to be clear, in `einsum` notation, you want `np.einsum('ij,ik,kj->ij',A,U,V)`?  (not that I"m suggesting using einsum).

Comment: In MATLAB how do you write this?  `A.*U*V`?

Comment: How sparse is your matrix A (i.e. number of non-zero elements)?

Comment: @Baptiste 1 million out of 0.1 billion, 1% nonzero entries.

Comment: How do you define "very slow"? On my laptop `A*(U.dot(V))` with the sizes above, and a dense A array takes 1.04 second to compute.  Are you sure you have Numpy compiled with a fast  BLAS library?  I cant see a way around explicitly calculating all the elements, even though A is sparse. On the other hand, how do you know that Matlab is not doing that too?

Comment: Intuitively I think there should be a way of using `A` to generate `U1` and `V1` such that `U1.dot(V1)` is your answer.  It might be easiest is each row and column of `A` has at most one `1`, but there should be a way even if there are multiple values.

Comment: @rth: I think you are correct. In MATLAB both `timeit(@() A.*(U*V))` and `timeit(@() U*V)` run about equally long. So the sparsity of `A` is only taken into account after `U*V` is calculated.

Comment: @moarningsun Yes you're write. It seems my numpy is extreamly low compared with Matlab in matrix multiplication. I use 'pip install scipy' to install scipy/numpy and it's linked to BLAS/LAPACK correctly (I don't have ATLAS installed).  Is that wrong?

Comment: @npbool Indeed it seems to be a problem with the BLAS configuration. If your Numpy is linked to ATLAS (check output of `numpy.show_config()`) you could try to install that too. Are you on Windows or Linux or..?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a test script and possible speedup.  The basic idea is to use the nonzero coordinates of `A` to select rows and columns of `U` and `V`, and then use `einsum` to perform a subset of the possible dot products.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

#M,N,d = 10,5,.1
#M,N,d = 1000,50,.1
M,N,d = 5000,50,.01   # about the limit for my memory

A=sparse.rand(M,M,d)
A.data[:] = 1   # a sparse 0,1 array
U=(np.arange(M*N)/(M*N)).reshape(M,N)
V=(np.arange(M*N)/(M*N)).reshape(N,M)

A1=A.multiply(U.dot(V))   # the direct solution
A2=np.einsum('ij,ik,kj->ij',A.A,U,V)

print(np.allclose(A1,A2))

def foo(A,U,V):
    # use A to select elements of U and V
    A3=A.copy()
    U1=U[A.row,:]
    V1=V[:,A.col]
    A3.data[:]=np.einsum('ij,ji->i',U1,V1)
    return A3

A3 = foo(A,U,V)

print(np.allclose(A1,A3.A))
```

The 3 solutions match.  For large arrays, `foo` is about 2x faster than the direct solution.  For small size, the pure `einsum` is competitive, but bogs down for large arrays.

The use of `dot` in `foo` would have computed too many products, `ij,jk->ik` as opposed to `ij,ji->i`.

Comment: Nice, using an array size (5000,50),  I get 1.51 s for the direct solution, 2.88 s for the einsum and 0.106 s for the `foo` function. So it's more like a x15 speed up.